# How to reverese a c-style string

Tags: c++, string

I would like to reverse a c-style string and came up with the following code.

[Play with the code](https://godbolt.org/z/fba18G)

```
#include <iostream>

void reverse_c_str(char *c)
{
    char *new_c = c;
    for (; *new_c; ++new_c){}    // find '\0'
    --new_c;                     // new_c is now at the actual last char, which is 'g'
    while (c < new_c)            // swap chars
    {
        char tmp = *c;
        *c = *new_c; // crash
        *new_c = tmp;
        --new_c;
        ++c;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char *c = "my string";
    reverse_c_str(c);
    std::cout << c << '\n';
}
```

Unfortunately, my code has an error, which I marked with `// crash`. Why does this line crash?

Comment: `char *c = "my string";` shouldn't compile in C++, a string literal is a `const char*` and you are not allowed to modify it

Comment: @UnholySheep it should not, but it sadly does, even with `-pedantic` it is "only" a warning.

Comment: Even though the conversion of string literals to `char *` was deprecated in C++98 and disallowed in C++11 (from memory), there is still a lot of code "in the wild" out there that uses it.  Hence there is continuing pressure on compiler vendors to continue allowing the conversion.   The path of least resistance for most compiler vendors is allowing the conversion and issuing a warning.   If you really want it to be picked up, and your compiler permits it, treat warnings as errors.

Comment: @t.niese is correct. The warning is `warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]`.

Comment: @User12547645 just to be clear errors are syntax errors. But warnings are not just something to ignore, with warnings the compiler tells you that something will probably go wrong at runtime. Whenever you see a warning by the compiler you should fix that warning.

Comment: Who would down vote this Q?  I don't see any problem with this Q?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"my string"` is a string literal, it is `const`.

It can be cast to a non-const `char *` for reasons of compatibility with C, but modifying a constant invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). In some cases the OS will prevent it (as when it's stored in a read-only section), which is probably what you're observing.

Make a copy of the string in automatic storage, then you'll be able to modify it:

```
int main()
{
    char c[] { "my string" };
    reverse_c_str(c);
    std::cout << c << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that response. I was really puzzled that my code did not work, but still does compile.

Comment: @User12547645 For some very strange reason, a lot of people seem to believe that code that compiles is automatically correct code. It is best to get rid of this misconception as early as possible because it was cause you nothing but pain.

Answer (score 0):

And of course there is a templated soultion:

```
#include <cstring>

template<std::size_t N>
void reverse_c_str(char (&str)[N]) {
    std::size_t len = N-1;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < len/2; ++i) {
        str[i] ^= str[len-i-1];
        str[len-i-1] ^= str[i];
        str[i] ^= str[len-i-1];
    }
}

int main() {
    char c[] {"123"};
    reverse_c_str(c);

    char c2[] {""};
    reverse_c_str(c2);

    char c3[] {"4321"};
    reverse_c_str(c3);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [std::swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) and [std::strlen](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen). I made example for you [here](https://onlinegdb.com/S1JhelNGw).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

void reverse_c_str(char *c) {
    int length = std::strlen(c);
    for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)
        std::swap(c[i], c[length - i - 1]);
}

int main()
{
    char c[] { "my string" };
    reverse_c_str(c);
    std::cout<<c << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Output:
gnirts ym
```

Another one version of function [reverse_c_str](https://onlinegdb.com/r1smQeVzD)

```
void reverse_c_str(char *c) {
    if(*c) {
        for(auto begin = c, end = c + std::strlen(c) - 1; 
            begin < end; ++begin, --end
            ) {
            std::swap(*begin, *end);
        }
    }
}
```